# HTACCESS redirect for multiple Vue router applications depending on URL

Tags: .htaccess, vue.js

Running three vue.js applications with vue-router on apache sever.

The HTACCESS redirects all non existing paths to /folder1/index.html. Now I want to include a redirect when the user accesses /folder2/success > /folder2/index.html instead of folder1/index.html

My current HTACCESS file looks as follows, however it isn't working it still redirects to folder1.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder1/index.html [L]
RewriteRule /folder2/success /folder2/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Really stuck on this any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Rules are executed in the order they are written. Since `/folder/success` does not exist as a file or directory, it is rewritten to `/folder/index.html`, which does not match your rule for `/folder2/success`.

Furthermore, since this is in a .htaccess file, it is in the context of that folder. The prefix of that folder is always removed from the part of the url that is matched, which means that the part that is matched **never** begins with a slash. You should be matching against `folder2/success` instead.

Your .htaccess file would look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^folder2/success /folder2/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder1/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it, I thought it might have been executing in the order it was written. What does the "^" do?

Comment: The first argument of `RewriteRule` is a regex that is used to test against the url. `^` matches against the beginning of the string. Using `^` there guards against the rule matching against `example.com/random/folder2/success` for example.